# Where is the default android "Up button" icon stored?

Tags: android

I need to add a navigation icon to my Toolbar, and I cannot use an ActionBar. Where is the default up button you'd get from using an ActionBar with homeAsUp enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find loads of material design icons [here](https://google.github.io/material-design-icons/), the pack also contains the up arrow.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the default icons for android in \path-to-your-android-sdk-folder\platforms\android-xx\data\res, your question is not very clear so if my answer doesn't fit, please give more details on what you want to realize , and maybe with illustrations.